# SSIS Why generate a new package id when upgrading?

Tags: ssis

SSIS Package Upgrade Wizard has an option to generate a new package ID during upgrade.  What is the benefit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a new package ID when you upgrade the package so that it will be a new package.  That way you could use the old package and the new package without conflict.  The GUID will identify the new package as a different package than the old one.

A package is identified by its ID (a GUID).  Whenever a log file gets written, the package ID is put into the log file.  If you had two different versions of a SSIS package both reporting the same name, you would have a hard time figuring out the log file.  That is why it is best practice to change the Package ID even when you are only creating a copy of the package (not even upgrading it).  Here is a link with more information about packages and their IDs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx